# Pass unknown number of variables to new page

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a form that allows users to make a multiple choice quiz. The quiz can have up to 9999 questions and 99 options for each question (should they really need it), then store that quiz in a database.

My problem is that I cannot work out how to put the user created quiz in to the database. I know the mysql INSERT command, but cannot work out (or find) how to determine how many form inputs are being passed from one page to the next.

I would normally do:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$choices = $_POST['choices'];

$quizData = "INSERT INTO quiz
        (name, choices)
        VALUES
        ('$name',
         '$choices')"
```

But how do I do this without knowing how many questions and choices there are?

Comment: Create as many  inputs as needed as arrays using `[]` in their name attr `<input type='text' name='name[]'>` Then loop over them in PHP `foreach ($_POST['name'] as $n)`

Comment: [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com) attack warning...

Comment: Marc B. Are you refering to my lack of security in the example? If so i will be adding security later, currently I am trying to create something I've never tried before so keeping everything as simple as possible. It not for a live site

Comment: Moving to PDO with prepared statements will clean up this code and make your life easier right now. Do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $_POST is an array, use foreach to set each question or answer into  the database or into it's own variable. If your fields are called questions, set them up like `<input type='text' name='questions[]'`, you can then count how many questions there are in the $_POST['questions'] or whatever you call your questions fields array using [**count()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php).

Comment: Once again, logical, but i would never have worked that out. Thanks. I will have a go and if I fail I'll get back for more advice :)